# Perl: printing lines in specific position in a file using a while loop

Tags: perl, printing, while-loop

I started a while loop as such:

```
open(INFO, "+<$file") or die("Could not open  file.\n");

while(defined ($line=<INFO>)){
last if ($line=~/^.end a/);
    if ($line=~/^.a/){
        print INFO "inside a\n";
        print INFO "still inside a\n";
    }
}
```

Here, we have a file called INFO which is stated as such:

```
1
2
3
4
.a
x 
y
z
.end a
```

Now after the above while loop, what I found, the printing inside INFO is from the beginning of its file, which is as such:

```
inside a
still inside a
3
4
.a
x 
y
z
.end a
```

What I wanted to do is: I want to add line after the ".a" not modifying the lines from the beginning, its hampering the file.

```
1
2
3
4
.a
inside a
still inside a
x 
y
z
.end a
```

Please help me to find out the solution of this simple problem.

thanks.

Comment: Reading the file contents into an array and looping through the array to the line number you wish to start writing would be a good way to do this, so long as the number of lines up to the point you wish to start writing isn't going to change. Once you've made your edits, write all the contents back out to the file.

Comment: Hi ryan, I can do it by array, problem is its very big file, more than 10 GB.

Comment: You'll have to do it in chunks then, same concept, only you don't read the whole file to the array, only certain chunks of it. You'd have to decide how many chunks to break it into. IE, open the file handle, loop through to a certain line number, then read from that point into an array that you can modify. You'll have to employ the same scheme to write back out to the file in the right position. There's not really a "simple" way for you to do what you want without some additional legwork.

Comment: I would consider checking out File::Slurp http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm

Comment: Welcome. If you just want a new line you could print INFO "\n" in your _if_ condition matching .a

Comment: @perlsufi `File::Slurp` doesn't change the fact that you'd be reading the entire 10 GB file into memory all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read: [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

It's not possible to modify a file in place unless you're working with fixed width records.

To insert lines like your trying to do, you ultimately have to create a new file and process the old file line by line.

In this case, I'd recommend using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to handle the creating of the new file for you.  However, there are other methods demonstrated in the above reference.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = '...';

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    print;
    if (/^\.a/) {
        print "inside a\n";
        print "still inside a\n";
    }
}
#unlink "$file$^I"; # Optionally delete backup
```

Comment: Probably.  Was just using his literal regex since it's just proof of concept code and data anyway.